# plugin Tipue search: Cómo activo el botón "buscar" para que realice la búsqueda al hacer clic

Tags: jquery, plugin

Estoy usando el plugin Tipue search para realizar búsquedas dentro de mi web y funciona muy bien, el problema es que las búsquedas las realiza solo al hacer Enter después de escribir en el cuadro de búsqueda. ¿Cómo activo el botón "buscar" para que realice la búsqueda al hacer clic en él?
Mi código es el siguiente:
[image: Código html del input]

```
 <form action="search.html"><div class="tipue_search_left"><img src="tipuesearch/search.png" class="tipue_search_icon"></div><div class="tipue_search_right"><input type="text" name="q" id="tipue_search_input" pattern=".{3,}" title="At least 3 characters" required></div><div style="clear: both;"></div></form>
```

[image: Cuadro de búsqueda web]
Espero haberme hecho entender. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Javier, te recomiendo que leas [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve], y luego edites la pregunta para añadir el código como texto (preferiblemente en un snippet) y no como imagen. De ese modo podremos ver el problema y ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="search.html">
<div style="float: left;">
   <input type="text" name="q" id="tipue_search_input">
</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 13px;">
   <!-- 
   Manda el input o botón con su evento onclick la función "SUBMIT",
   igual lo puedes hacer con JQuery, o un simple Javascript
   -->
   <input type="button" id="tipue_search_button" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="Buscar">
</div>
<div style="clear: left;"></div>
</form>
```